# How to find the current value for 'log_history' of PURGE_LOG job in Oracle

Tags: oracle, jobs

I was trying to find what is the value of 'log_history' of PURGE_LOG job in Oracle. 
I found that you can set the value using following command.

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_SCHEDULER_ATTRIBUTE
('log_history',<NUMBER_OF_DAYS>);
```

But I was not able to find any way to get what is the current value of this property. 
Could you please let me know if there is a way to do this?

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dbms_scheduler.get_scheduler_attribute('log_history',x);

do a desc on dbms_scheduler to see the possibilities...